Altium: Why don't connected rats nets to power plane using a via automatically remove?
I'm designing a 4 layer board Signal, GND, 3v3, Signal.
On the signal layer I place vias connected to the 3v3 net but I notice the associated rats nest doesn't disappear for these connections once they're placed.
If someone could explain why this happens that would be appreciated.
My vias have the correct net names and my power plane and ground plane have matching names.

My understanding is that the GND via goes to the internal GND layer. If my understanding is correct, I don't understand why the GND vias want to be connected according to the rats nest.
I've also double checked that the power and gnd layers do indeed have nets associated with them.

Hi,
It could mean that there is still some connections left to route. Usually the rats net connect to the next closest net connection.
Hope it makes sense.

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).
